# Se eu tenho 2 cartas, eu tenho uma DUPLA de cartas; se eu tenho 3, eu tenho uma TRIPLA de cartas?

Tags: substantivos, números

Recentemente, estava aprendendo pôquer e minha vó me falou "essa é a dupla". Eu fiquei curioso para saber o que vem depois de "dupla": seria uma "tripla"? Depois, uma "quádrupla"?

Eu gostaria de saber qual a seqüência, se há uma; e, também, se possível, o nome desse tipo de palavra, pois, de acordo com o Priberam, "dupla" é um substantivo e não um numeral.

Resumo: qual é a seqüência depois "dupla", tripla? E qual o nome desse tipo de substantivo, se há?

Comment: @stafusa, no pôquer, tem 315 para um monte de coisas.

Comment: 315? De qualquer forma, não quis dizer que todo o resto vejo sendo usado em inglês, só alguns. Coloco numa resposta e apago o comentário anterior.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem uma **trinca** ou, menos usado, "trio".

Considerando o livro [Como Jogar Poker e Vencer!](https://books.google.de/books?id=IaluBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT28&ots=ccteCpW5Sf&dq=p%C3%B4quer%20par%20trinca&pg=PT28#v=onepage&q=p%C3%B4quer%20par%20trinca&f=false), a [Lista de jogadas do pôquer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_jogadas_do_p%C3%B4quer) da Wikipédia e os sites [megajogos](https://www.megajogos.com.br/poker-online/regras) e [pokertips](http://pt.pokertips.org/rules/hand-rankings.php), as mãos do pôquer em português são:

- Sequência Real
- Sequência de (mesmo) Naipe (ou Sequência de Cor)
- Quadra
- *Full (House)*
- Sequência
- Trinca (ou Trio)
- Dois Pares
- Par
- Carta Alta

Answer (score 0):

O correto a ser utilizado é **trio**.

Triplo seria utilizado se fosse a continuidade de **dobro**. No entanto, como estamos falando de dupla (duas pessoas ou dois itens), o correto é utilizar **trio**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Estás certo, Chanp, mas, na minha experiência, usa-se mais *trinca* com cartas do que *trio*.

Answer (score -3):

Não existe uma tripla de cartas, não no carteado. A palavra trio é masculino, sendo assim é um trio de cartas, um quadruplo de cartas, um quíntuplo de cartas... Toda vez que o artigo for feminino usaremos "uma" e a palavra geralmente terminará com o artigo (a) no final e toda vez que o artigo for masculino, usaremos "um" e geralmente a palavra terminará com o artigo (o).

Comment: Duvido que seja trio-quádruplo-quíntuplo. Imagino que ou seja triplo-quádruplo-quíntuplo ou seja trio-quadra-quina.